# Vscode + NestJs modules infrequently not found

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, nestjs

This is really driving me nuts: I created a fresh new NestJs project with the @nestjs/cli command. At the beginning everything was fine. Then after adding a controller via `nest generate controller mycontroller` and installing types for jasmine and node, somehow the modules `@nestjs/testing` cannot be found anymore.

I recreated a new project over and over and always after a time I get this error, or an error for other packages of nestjs. (for example `@nestjs/common`).

I already deactivated nearly all extensions (only those that are really not likely to interfere with imports are still active, such as TSLint).

Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong? If it helps, here is my (autogenerated by nestjs) `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

- Node Version: 8.11.2
- Typescript: 2.9.1
- VsCode: 1.24.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this was a simple, dump configuration mistake:

The special thing was that I had a project structure like that:

```
base-project
 |
  -- sub-project
 |    |
 |    tsconfig.json
 |
 ...
```

and totally missed that I needed to set the `rootDir` property in tsconfig.json to `./sub-project`. After doing so, all modules could be found properly.

For those still having problems, you may also want to take a look at the property `baseUrl`.

Hope that helps others, having the same problem! Cheers

Comment: hahaa, thanks! I had the exact same problem =]